# Call two Interface methods successively in WP8

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, navigation, cimbalino

If I have a Interface like this:

```
public interface IImageService
{
    ObservableCollection<PictureModel> RefreshSavedImages();

    void PhotoChooserWithCameraServiceShow();
}
```

And his implementation is :

```
public class ImageService: IImageService
{
    public ObservableCollection<PictureModel> RefreshSavedImages()
    {
        // Refreash images from library
    }

    public WriteableBitmap StreamToWriteableBitmap(Stream imageStream)
    {
        WriteableBitmap image = new WriteableBitmap(1024, 768);
        image.SetSource(imageStream);
        imageStream.Dispose();
        return image;
    }

    public void PhotoChooserWithCameraServiceShow()
    {
        // PhotoChooserTask get source of image.
    }
}
```

When I have the implementation in a ViewModel:

```
private readonly IImageService imageService;
public MainViewModel(IImageService imageService)
    {
        this.imageService = imageService;
    }
private void MethodA()
    {
        // Choose Photo, I edited it and after saved it.
        imageService.PhotoChooserWithCameraServiceShow();
        // Refreash the library and Bind it in my ItemSource from my ListBox.
        PictureList = imageService.RefreshSavedImages();
    }
```

**My problem is that I need first finish this method: imageService.PhotoChooserWithCameraServiceShow(); and after continue with imageService.RefreshSavedImages();**

The problem is that what my program do is execute the second before the first is completed.

Problems that I think can cause this issue:

1. From a ViewModel call NavigationService without logic to goback. So the can't:

   NavigationService navigation = new NavigationService();
   navigation.NavigateTo(new Uri("/Views/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

The PhotoChooserWithCameraServiceShow is taken from the [Cimbalino Windows Phone Toolkit](http://cimbalino.org/)

Thanks for all and greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up an event listener for the photo chooser task's completed event and call `imageService.RefreshSavedImages();` from there.

If you update your interface, you can add an event handler to your `PhotoChooserWithCameraServiceShow` method:

```
public interface IImageService
{
    ObservableCollection<object> RefreshSavedImages();
    void PhotoChooserWithCameraServiceShow(EventHandler<PhotoResult> CompletedCallback);
}
```

Then in your interface implementation, assign that callback to the PhotoChooserTask Completed event. I'm assuming you're declaring your PhotoChooserTask in this class:

```
public class ImageService: IImageService
{
    PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask;
    public ImageService()
    {
        photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
    }        

    public ObservableCollection<PictureModel> RefreshSavedImages()
    {
        // Refreash images from library
    }

    public WriteableBitmap StreamToWriteableBitmap(Stream imageStream)
    {
       ....
    }

    public void PhotoChooserWithCameraServiceShowEventHandler<PhotoResult> CompletedCallback)
    {
        // PhotoChooserTask get source of image.
        photoChooserTask.Completed += CompletedCallback;        
    }
}
```

Finally, in your view model you can implement the actual callback:

```
private void MethodA()
{
    // Choose Photo, I edited it and after saved it.
    imageService.PhotoChooserWithCameraServiceShow(photoChooserTask_Completed);
}

// this is your callback
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            // Refreash the library and Bind it in my ItemSource from my ListBox.
            PictureList = imageService.RefreshSavedImages();
        }
    }
```

See the details and examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, but first I need to call my interface imageService.PhotoChooserWithCameraServiceShow();, who have photo edited and save logic. And After must done the imageService.RefreshSavedImages();

Comment: yes, of course. I just added additional setup steps you're missing. Your call to photoChooserTask.Show() is asynchronous and will immediately return. That is why you need to set up an event listener for the `OnCompleted` event. You could consider adding a delegate to your IImageService to handle the OnCompleted event if that's more of what you're looking for, but `RefreshSavedImages()` still needs to happen in/after this event.